# XSLT: Split Ungrouped Data into chunks

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I need to turn

```
   <question>
      <static><![CDATA[Static Data]]></static>

      <debit-row />
      <debit-row />
      <credit-row />

      <header><![CDATA[Header HTML 1]]></header>
      <debit-row />
      <debit-row />
      <credit-row />
   </question>
```

into

```
<p>Static Data</p>
<ul>
   <li>
      <table>
         <tr><td> debit row </td></tr>
         <tr><td> credit row </td></tr>
         <tr><td> credit row </td></tr>
      </table>
   </li>
   <li> Header HTML 1
      <table>
         <tr><td> debit row </td></tr>
         <tr><td> debit row </td></tr>
         <tr><td> credit row </td></tr>
      </table>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Essentially, either a header or a debit-row indicates the start of a new chunk.  Each chunk is a list item.  Each set or rows is a table (as a rule, credit rows always come last so it's easy to tell when to start the table).

XSLT and XPATH seem very difficult and I'm having a very hard time looking up anything that I want to do at all, so if anyone has an excellent reference, I would appreciate that too.

I've started out with this xsl:

```
<xsl:template match="question">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="static|header|debit-row[preceding-sibling::*[1] != header]" />
</xsl:template>
```

This is not a good start, because the templates are not applied to any debit-row at all, but they should be applied to the very first debit-row (it does not have a header element preceding it).  Is that expression wrong?

Even if I get that to work, I need to find a way to say "Open a `<ul>` if this is the very first header or debit-row," and I'm not sure how to do that when applying the header/debit-row template.  debit-row each has its own xml to be applied too (it needs a table row and td).  I also have to open and close the table appropriately before the first debit-row and after the last credit-row.

I would seriously appreciate any help as I am stuck even getting the simple xpath expression above to work correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I. XSLT 1.0 solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
 <xsl:key name="kFollowing"
  match="*[not(self::static or self::header)]"
  use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::*
                              [self::static
                              or
                               self::header
                              ][1]
                  )"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*[static]">
  <p><xsl:value-of select="static"/></p>
  <ul>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="static|header"/>
  </ul>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="static|header">
  <li>
    <xsl:value-of select=
     "concat(self::header, '&#xA;')"/>
    <table>
     <xsl:apply-templates
       select="key('kFollowing', generate-id())"/>
    </table>
  </li>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
  "*/*[not(self::static or self::header)]">
  <tr>
    <td>
     <xsl:value-of select=
      "translate(name(),'-', ' ')"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<question>
    <static><![CDATA[Static Data]]></static>
    <debit-row />
    <debit-row />
    <credit-row />
    <header><![CDATA[Header HTML 1]]></header>
    <debit-row />
    <debit-row />
    <credit-row />
</question>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<p>Static Data</p>
<ul>
   <li>

      <table>
         <tr>
            <td>debit row</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>debit row</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>credit row</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </li>
   <li>Header HTML 1
<table>
         <tr>
            <td>debit row</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>debit row</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>credit row</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </li>
</ul>
```

**Explanation**: Positional grouping using a key to define all elements that belong to a group.

---

**II. XSLT 2.0 solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*[static]">
  <p><xsl:value-of select="static"/></p>
  <ul>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="*"
         group-starting-with="static|header">
      <li>
        <xsl:value-of separator="&#xA;" select=
         "current-group()[1][self::header], ''"/>
        <table>
         <xsl:apply-templates
           select="current-group()[position() gt 1]"/>
        </table>
      </li>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </ul>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
  "*/*[not(self::static or self::header)]">
  <tr>
    <td>
     <xsl:value-of select=
      "translate(name(),'-', ' ')"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this XSLT 2.0 transformation is applied to the same XML document (above), again the same, correct result is produced**:

```
<p>Static Data</p>
<ul>
   <li>
      <table>
         <tr>
            <td>debit row</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>debit row</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>credit row</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </li>
   <li>Header HTML 1
<table>
         <tr>
            <td>debit row</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>debit row</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>credit row</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </li>
</ul>
```

**Explanation**: Using the XSLT 2.0 `<xsl:for-each-group>` instruction with a `group-starting-with` attribute. Also using the standard XSLT 2.0 function `current-group()`.